# URL encoding a BASH curl on UBUNTU

Tags: bash, curl, encode, urlencode

I'm passing the following line through a githook

```
curl -d \"githook[action]=code_commit\" -d \"githook[stats]=$encodestat\"  -d \"githook[project_key]=$Vproject\" -d \"githook[user_email]=$Vemail\" -d \"githook[description]=SM$encodemsg\" http://mydomain/githooks
```

If I echo this line I get

```
curl -d "githook[action]=code_commit" -d "githook[stats]=%201%20file%20changed%2C%201%20insertion%28%2B%29%2C%201%20deletion%28-%29" -d "githook[project_key]=divine_frost_994_147_5511" -d "githook[user_email]=steven@domain.uk" -d "githook[description]=SMtest%20git" http://mydomain.uk/githooks
```

which when I copy and paste executes and runs

however it refuses to execute with no errors when triggered in the first form in a githook

I literally cannot read the screen anymore :/

if anyone has any clues id be grateful, it was executing then I got a GLob error, tried it with -g and now it appears not to execute, rebooted, no joy

Comment: The first example is literal quotes due to the escaping, the second example the quotes are parsed by the shell and removed before `curl` is called. Just remove the `\\` escape from in front of the quotes in your first example.

Comment: I hope that user name and key in your output are not the real ones. Somebody might use them at this very moment.

Comment: They are test keys for a test domain, the project key is generated for each

Answer (score 0):

jordanm saw it straight away.

We are writing the hook file from an initializer and we didn't need the escaping quotes as bash injects the variables

I saw it when I got up this morning and slapped my forehead, don't code at night kids.

Would consider deleting as there's no learning here for anyone except me - to step away from the screen once every 12 hours?